# Pythonic dictionary in Javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structures, types, dictionary

How would you implement pythonic dictionary in Javascript that is able to store key value pairs and key can be tuple?

I'd like to find all anchors and then store values of it's `href` and `title` attributes to dictionary as keys (href value, title value) and number of occurrencies of this tuple as a value.

The code would look like this (it's a mix of Python and Javascript):

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll ("a");
d = []; // dictionary data structure
for (var i = 0, len = anchors.length; i < len; i++) {
  currentTuple = (anchors[i].href, anchors[i].title);
  if (!d.containsKey(currentTuple)) {
    d[currentTuple] = 1;
  } else {
   d[currentTuple] += 1;
  }
}
```

Maybe it would be easier if keys couldn't be tuples, but if it's possible i'd like to see it.

thank you

Comment: This library I've found quite useful for this purpose: http://www.timdown.co.uk/jshashtable/. If you implement a custom `.equals` function, it should work for your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this work? It just concatenates title and href as a unique key.

```
var data = [].reduce.call( document.links, function( data, a){
    var key = a.href+","+a.title;
    if( data[key] ) {
        data[key]++;
    }
    else {
        data[key] = 1;
    }   

return data;
}, {} );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/knYwb/

Comment: You might need to use a different special character or excape commas in the title in order to guarantee uniqueness

Comment: @missingno, what do you mean? the comma isn't even necessary for that it's just for readability when you dump the object in console.

Comment: The problem is that when you concatenate you can theoretically have two separate tuples that generate the same key.

Comment: @missingno, yes and then you increment the occurrence of that key by one. It has same title+href combination as a one that already exists.

Comment: No. You can have two *different* pairs like `("a," , "b")` and `("a" , ",b")` mapping to the same key `"a,,b"`

Comment: @missingno, yes but this is titles and hrefs. Is it even worth adding something like \0 there, just makes retrieving harder. I am in the javascript chatroom if you want to discuss.

Comment: @Esailija Looks interesting, but what if I want the dictionary to return list of all values? I'd like to get the maximum values, then I'd like to get a key with maximum value and split it to href and title.

Comment: @xralf you would just loop through the data object and see which values are highest and then split their keys by `,` if you're using `,` as a separator.

Comment: @Esailija Could I ask one little thing yet? Where the function console.log() logs data in the fiddle?

Comment: @Esailija And in firebug console that code writes only `undefined`. Shouldn't there be something for the case href or title doesn't exist?

Comment: @xralf You can see the object logged in your console, if you get undefined you are doing something very different and should show the code

Comment: @xralf, You could just use your browser to go to the jsfiddle and then open up the browser web developer console (ctrl+shift+j in google chrome) which shows it: http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/1118/linksei.png

Comment: @Esailija Chrome shows it, but when I append to the fiddle code `for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
    alert(data[i]);
}` I can't see nothing.

Comment: @xralf ? `data` is a plain object not an array. it doesn't have length property or indices.

Comment: @Esailija But you said, I can loop through it or use it. I'm not so knowledgeable in javascript to understand your code with `[].reduce.call()` Could you show me the looping and splitting as you describe above?

Comment: @xralf see here http://jsfiddle.net/knYwb/2/ note I am using null character as separator to simplify

Comment: @Esailija Thanks, this was my dream that javascript has `in` keyword and it's really there :-) .